# In-amp output clamps to reference voltage

Tags: instrumentation-amplifier

I am using [AD8231](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8231.pdf) instrumentation amplifier in unity gain configuration. I used the inbuilt op-amp to provide reference voltage as the datasheet suggests. A 4.4kHz sine wave generated with my professional signal generator (PC sound card) is fed into the non-inverting input of the in-amp.

[image]

Channel one is the input signal and channel two is the output of the in-amp. For some reason the output clamps near the reference voltage (1.6V).
[image]

The circuit is built on a breadboard and I haven't used decoupling and filtering capacitors since I'm prototyping. Here is a photo of the breadboard in case it helps:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Table 3 on page 5 of the linked datasheet gives a minimum input voltage of 0.05 V. It looks like you are driving the input voltage at +INA to below ground, so you are violating this requirement.

Probably there are esd protection diodes on the input pins that are short-circuiting the input to ground when you try to drive it negative.

Comment: Damn, it seems to be the case. I thought that setting the reference voltage to mid-supply will offset the input signal and allow the inputs to go negative.

Comment: If you offset the `-INA` input and also center the input signal around that voltage (for example, by ac-coupling), you should be able to get the results you want.

Comment: Alos, the `REF` input probably only affects the last stage of the amplifier. The input stages most likely are not affected at all by what you do wit the `REF` input.

Comment: I don't really "get" a single supply instrument amp. The sample circuit in the spec sheet are all for split supplies.